# Черная полоса на видео при использовании LibVLC android

Tags: android, видео, vlc, rtmp

При использовании libVLC на некоторых устройствах появляется черная полоска внизу видео. Например исходное видео имеет размер 640х360 а высота в параметре mVideoHeight показывает 386. из-за этого получается черная полоса размером в 16 пикселей при отображении на SurfaceView. Как это можно исправить?

Comment: также и с видео 720х480 mVideoHeight показывает 482 - дополнительные 2 пикселя. проблема замечена пока на андроид 2.3 и 4.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пришлось размещать SurfaceView внутри FrameLayout и при расчете размера для отображения на экране вычислять размер LayoutParams для каждого.